# How to make top textarea blank when new row is added

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Pc4B/10/. In the jsfiddle, type in a question in the textarea and then click on the "Add Question" button. This adds the question in a new row underneath but the problem is that when this happens, the textarea at the top still displays the question. I want it so that if the user has clicked on the "Add Question" button AND if the question is added in a new row, then the textarea on top should go blank. How can this work?

Below is code to make the textarea blank:

```
var area = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = area.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
if ('questionText'===area[i].name) area[i].value = "";
}
```

Where do I display this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add:

```
$('#questionTextArea').val('');
```

Below the line:

```
$question.append($questionText);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Pc4B/11/).

---

**Edited** in response to question from OP, [user1182476](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182476/user1182476), in comments, below:

> By the way, If I have a radio button which is selected but after adding a table row I want all the radio buttons to be unchecked, how do I do this?

To un-check all radio buttons:

```
$('input:radio:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

It seems that you, essentially, want to reset the form back to its default state, though, and to do that you might find it easier to simply use:

```
$('#enter')[0].reset();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Pc4B/13/).

Or:

```
document.getElementById('enter').reset();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Pc4B/14/).

Inserting either of these lines, as shown in the linked demos, instead of the line supplied in the first version of this answer (so after the same line as before: `$question.append($questionText);`).

The reason for using `[0]` in the first example, and `document.getElementById()` in the latter, is because the `reset()` method works on the plain JavaScript DOM node, not the jQuery element.

Comment: By the way, If I have a radio button which is selected but after adding a table row I want all the radio buttons to be unchecked, how do I do this?